# Meta annotation for @Controller doesn't work in Micronaut

Tags: kotlin, annotations, micronaut

I am trying to implement a custom annotation (meta annotation) for `@Controller` as follows:

```kotlin
@MustBeDocumented
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
@Secured(SecurityRule.IS_AUTHENTICATED)
@Controller
annotation class CustomController(

    @get:AliasFor(annotation = Controller::class)
    val value: String
)

//Usage:

@CustomController("/demo-api")
class ChangeController(private val changeGroupApi: ChangeGroupApi) {

   //...
}
```

However, Micronaut behaves as if the controller class isn't even annotated at all. See related log, it's the same with that when the class isn't annotated.

Related log:

```
10:56:47.351 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] DEBUG i.m.s.rules.InterceptUrlMapRule - One or more of the IP patterns matched the host address [127.0.0.1]. Continuing request processing.
10:56:47.352 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] DEBUG i.m.s.rules.InterceptUrlMapRule - No url map pattern exact match found for path [/demo-api] and method [GET]. Searching in patterns with no defined method.
10:56:47.352 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] DEBUG i.m.s.rules.InterceptUrlMapRule - No url map pattern match found for path [/demo-api]. Returning unknown.
10:56:47.352 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] DEBUG i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - Authorized request GET /demo-api. No rule provider authorized or rejected the request.
```

Any ideas to make it work?